# XAMPP for Mac : “forbidden access” when trying to set more secure permissions

Tags: mac, permissions, apache-http-server, webserver, xampp

I've installed XAMPP on my Mac running Lion and I've set the DocumentRoot to `Users/myusername/Sites`. Apache runs as `myusername/_www` (user/group, 755) and everything is OK, my browser can access all pages without any problem.

BUT I'd like to increase security, as some HTML pages are to be accessed from the Internet, not only locally.

So I set Apache to run as `_www/_www`, I changed all permissions of my `Users/myusername/Sites` folders and files to `_www/_www` (755 too) and I restarted Apache.

The problem is : nothing works... All access is forbidden, and all I got is `(13)Permission denied: access to / denied` in the console.

And I can't understand why.  What's going on?

Comment: Any other logs? Is it possible to enable verbose logging? Are you *sure* Apache is now running as `_www` (`ps` output?)? Are all parent directories of your *Sites* directory executable (traversable) by Apache?

Comment: Enabling verbose logging doesn't give more info. OS X's "Activity monitor" gives 7 httpd processes as `_www` and 1 httpd process as `root`.

Comment: Regarding the parent directories: `Users` is set to `root/admin` and `myusername` is set to `myusername/admin`. Is there something to be done there to allow Apache (running as `_www`) to access `Users/myusername/Sites/`?

Comment: What are the permissions (not just ownership) on /, /Users, /Users/myusername, and /Users/myusername/Sites?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot them: they are `755` for all directories.